# Satellite return ro Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, potential-energy, rocket-science, satellites

When satellite is return from space orbit to earth how they lower the potential energy? Do satellite need to fire engines as they launch?
How we apply energy conservation laws?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, satellite needs to fire engines to slow down and begin descending. It's necessary to direct engines forward, so that the speed of satellite decreases. As a result of decreasing speed the satellite descends to lower orbit, enters atmosphere and after that it's air friction that further decreases satellites speed.

But how come that when satellite just started engines it's speed (and hence the energy) decrease? The burning fuel produce energy, so the energy of satellite must increase!

Well, it does not have to decrease, because the satellite is not a closed system. It's engines emit gas, and it's the total kinetic energy of satellite and the gas that must increase. As engines are directed "forward", the speed of atoms emitted by the engines are higher than the speed of these atoms when they were still inside satellite. So, their kinetic energy increased. And even though the kinetic energy of satellite decreases, total kinetic energy of the satellite and gases do not decrease.